# Application Scope settings or something else

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am in the process of building a completely fresh version of an application that has been in existence for a good many years.  I can look back with horror now at some of the things I had done, but the whole point of life is to learn as we go along.  The nice thing now is that I have a clean slate from which to work, and it's because of that that I thought that I would seek some advice from you all.

User settings are great for those things that each individual user would naturally want to and ought to be able to change, a theme or visual style for example.  Application settings should quite obviously apply to the entire application irrespective of whoever uses it.

Somewhere in the middle though are a set of settings that I would like to give the system administrator the opportunity to change (default work periods, appointment time slots, the currency the company wants to use as its main trading one etc etc).  These can't be user settings because individual users should not be able to change them, nor should they be application settings because I as the developer have no idea what the end user (or to be more exact the senior end user) would want to set them to.

Many years ago I might have considered writing such settings to the registry, or an ini file.  I could perhaps (as this is an application that is tightly integrated with its own custom database) create a one off settings table, and read in the relevant settings at program startup.  I could perhaps opt for a separate 'universal settings' xml configuration file stored in the all users directory.  Clearly a number of options.

What I would like to try and establish though is the most efficient way to approach this.  What is the best trade off between file read and write operations as against reading everything into a set of public constants at application start-up?  These are not going to be settings that will only be referred to occasionally so efficiency is going to be key.

Just so that there is no ambiguity as to what the application will be.  Traditional winforms, using vs 2012 as the development ide and vb.net as the code base based on .net4.5 and ef 5.0.  Backend data to be stored in either sql express or full sql server.  Target operating system for end users will be windows 7 or above (so due respect for the uac will be required).

I'd welcome any suggestions that you might have.

Comment: I don't understand "nor should they be application settings because I as the developer have no idea what the end user would want to set them to." - if you need that value, surely you've got to default it to something (even if just during test)?

Comment: That's a very fair point, and obviously I'll need to apply some default settings to these values in order to run tests.  It's the most efficient way to both store and retrieve these that I'd like to try and implement.